# Intellij-IDEA: How to sort members alphabetically?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

I am using Intellij-IDEA 12. Most of team mates use Eclipse and while saving it sorts members automatically first based on Visibility and then Alphabetically. I want to mimic the same functionality in Intellij. But it seems that when I choose arrange members alphabetically, it overrides visibility (and all other) rules. How can I sort members based on Visibility (Public - Default  - Private ) and within that sub-group sort them Alphabetically?

Edit: This assumption made in the question is wrong. Like mentioned in the Answer by @Maba, creating separate rows and marking them as "Order Alphabetically" works as expected. ( I had separate rows for fields but failed to create separate rows for Methods and hence the confusion.)

Comment: Did you try out my answer?

Comment: I did. That was the first thing I had tried.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Create separate rows for the different method visibilities in the `Arrangement` part of the `Code Style`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In IntelliJ 15 I had to modify the order type of the default matching rules to obtain the expected behavior.

Comment: Note that combining the alias `by visibility` and `Order: order by name` did not sort the methods first by visibility and within visibilities by name. I had to add a rule for each visibility and select `Order: order by name`.

Comment: How can I apply an order choice to one or more rules at once?

Comment: Worth mentioning that to see the pane with the Order dropdown you need to right-click on the matching rule and select "Edit rule". *However, this wasn't a good solution for me as I didn't want my code formatter to order fields every time I format the code - only for a one-off. I ended up sorting them manually this time but would hope there might be an easier way.*